# Dynamicly creating imageButton that calls a JavaScript function in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have the following c# code that creates image buttons which should call the javaScript method below

```
var imageButton = new ImageButton();
    imageButton.ImageUrl = "Styles/unClicked.png";
    imageButton.ID = "btn" + questionName;
    imageButton.OnClientClick = "buttonPressed('" + questionName + "')";
```

Its outputting & # 3 9; instead of the ' in the html code and there for is causing an error (Ive had to add spaces tp prevent SO changing it to a comma)

```
onclick="buttonPressed(&#39;question0&#39;)
```

how to I prevent this?

Comment: so what's the problem. sorry its not very clear

Comment: The problem is that HTML returned is encoded, and it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one [HtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.htmlstring.aspx) (not working).

```
imageButton.OnClientClick = new HtmlString("buttonPressed('" + questionName + "')");
```

If it will not work, than you will need to create custom *control* or use javascript (JQuery) to add handler for [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event.

```
<script>    
    $("<%=imageButton.ID%>").click(function() {
      buttonPressed('<%=questionName%>');
      })
</script>
```

Comment: tried the top way, but I jusk kept getting an error saying that it cant implicitly comvert HTMLString to String. Is there a way arround this?

Comment: sorry that I have asked you to try it. Alternative options I gave in my answer too.

Comment: No, thanks for your time. Could you exsplain the second one a little more please?

Comment: First you should create control as you did before, without 'OnClientClick' property. Then you need to add javascript code that will add event handler for this html element (imageButton will be rendered in this element).

Answer (score 0):

The OnClientClick attribute is very limiting.  Not totally sure this will work, but I have use similar code before to handle ghost text in textboxes...

```
imageButton.Attributes.Add("onclick", "buttonPressed('" + val + "')");
```

The attribute should not be HTML encoded.